# Write a 440 Hz Sine Wave to .wav-File using Python and SciPy

Tags: audio, python, frequency, scipy

This is my first post on DSP.SE! I'm a student in Computer Sciences and am just getting started with Signals and Systems, thus getting in touch with discrete signals and analyzing them.

I wanted to explore this world a little further and so my first goal is to create a Sine Wave that has a Frequency of 440 Hz and write it to a .wav-File. Of course i have all the calculus in mind, but i can't seem to figure out the problem myself!

So far, i have this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
from scipy.io import wavfile

sampleRate = 44100

t = np.linspace(0, 20, sampleRate * 5)  #  Produces a 5 second Audio-File
y = np.sin(440 * t)  #  Should have frequency of 440Hz

wavfile.write('Sine.wav', sampleRate, y)
```

I understand why this code always creates a File, that is 5 seconds long, but i can't figure out, how to get the frequency right!

Have i even gotten the rest of the code right, Dsp-Guy-wise?

Comment: should maybe be `t = np.linspace(0, 5, sampleRate*5 + 1)`.

Comment: oh, and welcome to dsp.se .  this might be a better question for Stack Overflow, but i dunno.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I already figured the solution out myself, see my answer!

Comment: Actually, maybe math.se would also have been a good fit! I hope i haven't posted absolutely the wrong way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some experimenting I came up with the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
from scipy.io import wavfile

sampleRate = 44100
frequency = 440
length = 5

t = np.linspace(0, length, sampleRate * length)  #  Produces a 5 second Audio-File
y = np.sin(frequency * 2 * np.pi * t)  #  Has frequency of 440Hz
    
m = np.max(np.abs(y))
print("m", m)

maxint16 = np.iinfo(np.int16).max  # == 2**15-1
print("maxint16", maxint16)

# You have to Normalize the audio
y = maxint16 * y / m

# You have to convert to int16, else doesn't work
y = y.astype(np.int16) 

wavfile.write('Sine.wav', sampleRate, y)
```

I pulled out one of my math-books and figured out how to write the sine-function:

Since sin(x) has a period of 2*pi, sin(2*pi*x) has a period of 1/Frequency of 1Hz. Thus, sin(440*2*pi*x) has a Frequency of 440Hz.

The last thing that was unclear to me was how to get the array-length and element-count right!

Opting for a File that has a sample rate of 5 seconds at 44.1 kHz Sample Rate, i need 5 * 44.1k samples, so that was already ok. But since sin(440*2*pi*x) performs 440 periods until t == 1, the array simply has to have a duration of 5 (5 seconds in my case to be precise). enlarging the array boundaries would have squished the array-values together, resulting in a higher pitched sound.

Sorry to anyone that has already scratched their head, I probably should have thought for a little bit longer!

Comment: Good to see you figured it out. I'd suggest using `duration` instead of `length` to avoid confusion -- `length` usually means "number of elements".

Comment: how many actual number of elements are produced by `linspace()`?  i think the length of the vector is the last argument to the function (if it's anything like MATLAB's `linspace()`).  in that case, i am pretty sure you want $$ $$ `t = np.linspace(0, length, sampleRate*length+1)` $$ $$ otherwise you will be slightly detuned. this is a "fencepost" or "off-by-one" sorta problem.

Comment: No, it creates exactly as much elements, as the third Argument specified. When i do len(t) i get 220500. 220500/5 = 44100 => SampleRate

Comment: But the Index of the elements is always len() - 1. So if i want to edit the last element of t, i would have to write t[len(t) - 1] = value, at least if i'm not mistaken

Comment: I investigated a little bit: you can set behavior yourself, according to https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html in linspace, setting endpoint=False, the last wouldn't bei included in the array, Default is True.

Comment: Good work . But this isn't compatible with the `wave` python package. It cannot read the file. Any thoughts on how to make it so?

Comment: Sorry, I’m not familiar with the wave-library.